# Video and image thumbnails in the file browser?

Tags: raspbian

Is there a way I could have Raspbian show me thumbnail previews of videos and images? One time in Ubuntu I had to apt-get a thumbnailer, but I can no longer find it.

Answer (score 0):

PCManFM already has an option to set `Folder View Mode` to **Thumbnail View**

Comment: well I don't have it in "list" mode. it is in the view mode that should have thumbnail previews.  (a small picture showing the image or a clip from a video that represents the icon of the file) like I don't mean just a thumbnail cause believe me there are tons of icons of film reals and jpg icons or whatever you wanna call them but when I have a 100 videos all names videoplayback(some large number).mp4 it is  really really handy to have images to show you what is in the file.  I am basically trying to ask, is my pi supposed to have out of the box support or do I have to apt-get something???

Answer (score 0):

In RPi4 folder contents display there is very much an icon "view as thumbnails" in the tool bar at top, by clicking which the plain icons of content files are converted to thumbnail images.